# Multi-line time series color-coded by attribute in another dataframe (plotly/ggplot2 on pandas/R)

Tags: python, r, pandas, ggplot2, time-series

I have a typical panel dataframe for stock prices where date is the index and each column represents a stock (thus, entry (i,j) is the stock price of j at date i). I also have information regarding the industry of the company behind each stock in another dataframe. I want to plot a time series graph (x='Date') with one line per stock. The catch is that I also want the lines to be color-coded by industry, using the second dataframe.

The end goal is to have an interactive graph, so this could be done directly with plotly in python, or through R, starting with a ggplot2 object that plotly can then read.

For minimal reproduceable examples, these .csv files can be read to python/R:

```
#df1
Date, StockA, StockB, StockC
2020-01-02, 1, 1, 1
2020-01-03, 2, 1, 3
2020-01-04, 4, 2, 5

#df2
, Stock, Industry
0, StockA, IndustryI
1, StockB, IndustryII
2, StockC, IndustryI
```

By reading these in R, you'd get:

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(Date = c("2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-04"
), StockA = c(1L, 2L, 4L), StockB = c(1L, 1L, 2L), StockC = c(1L, 
3L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
> dput(df2)
structure(list(X = 0:2, Stock = c(" StockA", " StockB", " StockC"
), Industry = c(" IndustryI", " IndustryII", " IndustryI")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Convert `df1` to a tidy format using `pivot_longer`.  Then join it with `df2` to obtain a single data frame containg both `Stock` and `Industry`.  Help us to help you by providing `df1` and `df2` as the output from calls to `dput()`.

Comment: Done! Edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Python:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-04'],
 'StockA': [1, 2, 4],
 'StockB': [1, 1, 2],
 'StockC': [1, 3, 5]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Stock': ['StockA', 'StockB', 'StockC'],
 'Industry': ['IndustryI', 'IndustryII', 'IndustryI']})
```

Create a dataframe with stock and industry data in the long form:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1.melt(id_vars="Date", var_name="Stock", value_name="Price"),
               df2,
               on="Stock",
               how="left")
```

This gives:

```
   Date        Stock      Price    Industry
0  2020-01-02  StockA     1        IndustryI
1  2020-01-03  StockA     2        IndustryI
2  2020-01-04  StockA     4        IndustryI
3  2020-01-02  StockB     1        IndustryII
4  2020-01-03  StockB     1        IndustryII
5  2020-01-04  StockB     2        IndustryII
6  2020-01-02  StockC     1        IndustryI
7  2020-01-03  StockC     3        IndustryI
8  2020-01-04  StockC     5        IndustryI
```

Then use Plotly Express to create the plot:

```
import plotly.express as px
px.line(df3, x="Date", y="Price", color="Industry", line_group="Stock")
```

[image: stock prices]

Answer (score 1):

Note I have removed the leading spaces from your `df2`.

```
structure(list(X = 0:2, Stock = c("StockA", "StockB", "StockC"
), Industry = c("IndustryI", "IndustryII", "IndustryI")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                 -3L))

library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols=starts_with("Stock"), 
    values_to="Value", 
    names_to="Stock") %>% 
  left_join(
    df2,
    by="Stock"
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=as.Date(Date), y=Value, colour=Stock, linetype=Industry)) +
    geom_line()
```

Giving

[image]